# Definition of Tensor Product of Graphs

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, tensor-products

Let $G$ and $H$ be graphs, then connect two elements $(g, h)$ and $(g', h')$ of $G\times H$ if and only if $gg'\in G$ and $hh' \in H$.

Does the tensor product of graphs have to do with the tensor product in other areas?

E.g is there a general "tensor product of structures", or is the word "tensor product" a bit like "number system"?

I know the graph tensor product is the same as the $0$-$1$ matrix tensor product.

But how are they connected to other tensor products?

Answer (score 2):

The adjacency matrix of $G \times H$ is the tensor product of the adjacency matrices of $G$ and $H$.

Also there is the notion of a monoidal category (also called a tensor category).  The category whose objects are graphs and whose morphisms are graph homomorphisms has a monoidal structure given by the tensor product of graphs.

Comment: What exactly does it mean to have a monoidal structure?

Comment: If $\mathcal C$ is a category, then $\mathcal C$ has a monoidal structure if there is a bifunctor $\otimes\colon\mathcal C \times \mathcal C \to \mathcal C$ which satisfies a few axioms, for example that it is associative and that there is a unit.  The standard example is modules over a commutative ring $A$.  Take $\otimes$ to be the tensor product over $A$ and $A$ itself the unit (because $A \otimes_A M \simeq M$).